# prediction functions in both codes of classifications got errors

Tags: python-3.x

I have created the following codes, for prediction functions in both I got errors. Can you please help me to figure out the issue?  As if I change the variable to X_train it works,however with X_test i got errors

```
# Load libraries
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier # Import Decision Tree Classifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split # Import train_test_split function
from sklearn import metrics #Import scikit-learn metrics module for accuracy calculation


col_names = ['pregnant', 'glucose', 'bp', 'skin', 'insulin', 'bmi', 'pedigree', 'age', 'label']
# load dataset
pima = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv", header=None, names=col_names)

#split dataset in features and target variable
feature_cols = ['pregnant', 'insulin', 'bmi', 'age','glucose','bp','pedigree']
X = pima[feature_cols] # Features
y = pima.label # Target variable

# Split dataset into training set and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1) # 70% training and 30% test


# Create Decision Tree classifer object
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()

# Train Decision Tree Classifer
clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

#Predict the response for test dataset
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

# Predict and print the label for the new data point X_new
new_prediction = clf.predict(X_test)
print("Prediction: {}".format(new_prediction))


# Model Accuracy, how often is the classifier correct?
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

And

```
# Load libraries
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split # Import train_test_split function
from sklearn import metrics #Import scikit-learn metrics module for accuracy calculation
#Import Gaussian Naive Bayes model
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

col_names = ['pregnant', 'glucose', 'bp', 'skin', 'insulin', 'bmi', 'pedigree', 'age', 'label']
# load dataset
pima = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv", header=None, names=col_names)

#split dataset in features and target variable
feature_cols = ['pregnant', 'insulin', 'bmi', 'age','glucose','bp','pedigree']
X = pima[feature_cols] # Features
y = pima.label # Target variable

# Split dataset into training set and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1) # 70% training and 30% test

#Create a Gaussian Classifier
model = GaussianNB()
# Train DGaussian Classifier
model = model.fit(X_train,y_train)
#Predict the response for test dataset
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# Predict and print the label for the new data point X_new
new_prediction = model.predict(X_test)
print("Prediction: {}".format(new_prediction))
```

I have created the following codes, for prediction functions in both I got errors. Can you please help me to figure out the issue?  As if I change the variable to X_train it works,however with X_test i got errors

Comment: Hi Ala'a. Can you show us your errors? You also might want to check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4e7112f8c8eb> in <module>()
     26 
     27 #Predict the response for test dataset
---> 28 y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
     29 
     30 # Predict and print the label for the new data point X_new

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d9a99e8d3bac> in <module>()
     24 
     25 #Predict the response for test dataset
---> 26 y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
     27 
     28 # Predict and print the label for the new data point X_new

Comment: 446         # make sure we actually converted to numeric:
    447         if dtype_numeric and array.dtype.kind == "O":
--> 448             array = array.astype(np.float64)
    449         if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
    450             raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'DiabetesPedigreeFunction'

Comment: can you try adding the errors to the original post? It's hard to read in the comments!

Answer (score 0):

I can't duplicate your error based on the code provided (it refers to a CSV input that I don't have locally), but if I use `sklearn.datasets.load_diabetes()` directly, it seems to work perfectly. I modified the top part of your code to be the following:

```
# col_names = ['pregnant', 'glucose', 'bp', 'skin', 'insulin', 'bmi', 'pedigree', 'age', 'label']
# load dataset
# pima = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv", header=None, names=col_names)

#split dataset in features and target variable
# feature_cols = ['pregnant', 'insulin', 'bmi', 'age','glucose','bp','pedigree']
# X = pima[feature_cols] # Features
# y = pima.label # Target variable
X, y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True) # load the data directly into X, y
# (...rest of code unchanged from this point)
```

Give that a try - does simply changing the data source input get rid of that error?